# SCSS boolean property not working on :active property

Tags: sass, boolean

I have set boolean variable to false and on click of button I want to change its background color in scss file. But it looks like display variable is not set to true on :active, how can I achieve this functionality?

Here is my scss file

```
$display : false;

.bot {
  &:active {
    $display: true;

    display: none;
  }

}

@if $display {
  .bot {
    background-color: brown;

  }
}
```

Here is my html file

```
<button class="bot" (click)="xy()">Table
    </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to implement what you want to achieve is simply toggling the `.active` CSS selector using JavaScript:

HTML

```
<button class="bot" onclick="xy()">Table</button>
```

Scss

```
.bot {
  background-color: brown;
  &:active {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

JavaScript function

```
const xy = () => {
   let btn = document.querySelector("button");
   btn.classList.toggle(":active");
}
```

See it working in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ezpvc16m/2/

It makes no sense toggling a CSS selector like `:active` using Sass variables and booleans; `:active` already works like `true` or `false`. It is activated whenever an element (in this case, a button) is activated by a user. Otherwise, it's not activated.

--
Also, keep in mind that Sass is compiled to CSS and CSS doesn't have access to Sass variables and booleans.